# chromium web app integration notifications not working?

Tags: unity, chromium, notification

Ubuntu 13.04, Chromium 28, unity-chromium-extension 2.4.7.

I was able to add Google plus and Gmail as short-cuts it seems. But when I set an email as read only I do not get a notification popup, nor does Gmail under the task-bar icon show any emails as unread. The task-bar drop-down menu does show the Gmail icon however.

is there some setting I need to enable? Or is this a new bug that 2.4.7 was supposed to fix.

Answer (score 0):

Have you downloaded all the unity webapps?

If not, try the command: sudo apt-get install unity-webapps-* and this will install all the unity webapps.

Comment: that did not fix it.